# Nearby Google API doesn't find Eddystone beacons

Tags: swift, beacon, eddystone, google-nearby

I'm trying to use Nearby API to scan **Eddystone BLE** with Swift, I've made the same calls:

```
if let messageMgr = self.messageMgr {    
        let params: GNSSubscriptionParams = GNSSubscriptionParams.init(strategy:
            GNSStrategy.init(paramsBlock: { (params: GNSStrategyParams!) -> Void in
                params.includeBLEBeacons = true;
            }))
        subscription = messageMgr.subscriptionWithParams(params,
            messageFoundHandler:{[unowned self] (message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in
                self.messageViewController.addMessage(String(data: message.content, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))
            },
            messageLostHandler: {[unowned self](message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in
                self.messageViewController.removeMessage(String(data: message.content, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))})
    }
}
```

BUT !!! I detect **0 beacon** you can see it in my screen log : ==>

```
2016-02-19 15:06:54.870 NearbyBeaconTestGoogle[452:55363] Beacon: Start scanning
2016-02-19 15:06:54.882 NearbyBeaconTestGoogle[452:55363] Tokens: 0 good, 0 bad, 3 broadcast
2016-02-19 15:06:54.882 NearbyBeaconTestGoogle[452:55363] Report RPC request: 3 token(s), 0 beacon(s), 6 directive(s)
2016-02-19 15:06:55.351 NearbyBeaconTestGoogle[452:55363] Report RPC response: Success
```

Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: Sarra, how is the beacon configured?  The Nearby Messages library will only scan for beacons configured with an Eddystone-UID; it won't find beacons configured with Eddystone-URL or Eddystone-TLM.

Comment: Thanks Dan, but i've configured the Eddystone beacon with Eddystone-UID frame and it works perfectly with android. but i still can't get the ios scan

Comment: Sarra, here are a few more things to check:
(1) Does your app have permission to use location?  It's required for beacon scanning.  Check Settings->Privacy->Location Services.
(2) Is Bluetooth turned on?
(3) How long have you waited while it's scanning?  Sometimes it can take some time to see beacons.  Let it scan for a minute or two just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, but from what I know we don't need a location permission we just need Bluetooth permission for the **Eddystone-UID** beacon detection cause the **Nearby AP**I is using **CoreBluetooth** only.  
I'm using the  **GNSPermission** object for managing it. but I may be wrong on that.

Comment: Sarra, I'm at a loss to explain why your app isn't seeing any beacons.  If there are any Eddystone-UID beacons nearby, the logs should report "N beacon(s)".  Other ideas: (a) try a different iOS device; (b) try with another Eddystone-UID beacon; (c) keep scanning for a minute or two, just to be sure.  Regarding GNSPermission: This manages the Nearby permission status, which is required for Nearby to do any kinds of discovery operations; if it were disabled, you wouldn't see any of the Nearby logs you're seeing.  I'll try to think of any other reason beacon scanning wouldn't be working.

Comment: And you're right about not needing location permission for Eddystone beacons; I was thinking about iBeacons.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember but I will test it for you and check if the problem persist